# Removing replacement character � from column

Tags: sql, teradata

Based on my research so far this character indicates bad encoding between the database and front end. Unfortunately, I don't have any control over either of those. I'm using Teradata Studio.

How can I filter this character out? I'm trying to perform a `REGEX_SUBSTR` function on a column that occasionally contains `�`, which throws the error "The string contains an untranslatable character".

Here is my SQL. `AIRCFT_POSITN_ID` is the column that contains the replacement character.

```
 SELECT DISTINCT AIRCFT_POSITN_ID, 
 REGEXP_SUBSTR(AIRCFT_POSITN_ID, '[0-9]+') AS AUTOROW
 FROM PROD_MAE_MNTNC_VW.FMR_DISCRPNCY_DFRL 
 WHERE DFRL_CREATE_TMS > CURRENT_DATE -25
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your diagnostic is correct, so first of all, you might want to check the **Session Character Set** (it is part of the connection definition).
If it is **ASCII** change it to **UTF8** and you will be able to see the original characters instead of the substitute character.

---

And in case the character is indeed part of the data and not just an indication for encoding translations issues:

The substitute character AKA  **SUB** (DEC: 26 HEX: 1A) is quite unique in Teradata.

you cannot use it directly -

```
select  '�';

-- [6706] The string contains an untranslatable character.
```

---

```
select  '1A'XC;

-- [6706] The string contains an untranslatable character.
```

If you are using version 14.0 or above you can generate it with the **CHR** function:

```
select  chr(26);
```

If you're below version 14.0 you can generate it like this:

```
select  translate (_unicode '05D0'XC using unicode_to_latin with error);
```

---

Once you have generated the character you can now use it with **REPLACE** or **OTRANSLATE**

```
create multiset table t (i int,txt varchar(100) character set latin) unique primary index (i);

insert into t (i,txt) values (1,translate ('Hello שלום world עולם' using unicode_to_latin with error));
```

---

```
select * from t;

-- Hello ���� world ����
```

---

```
select otranslate (txt,chr(26),'') from t;

-- Hello  world 

select otranslate (txt,translate (_unicode '05D0'XC using unicode_to_latin with error),'') from t;

-- Hello  world
```

---

BTW, there are 2 versions for **OTRANSLATE** and **OREPLACE**:

- The functions under **syslib** works with **LATIN**.
- the functions under **TD_SYSFNLIB** works with **UNICODE**.

Comment: Can you show a working `oTranslate`, for me it always failed. Afaik only the `Udf_checklatin` function from Teradata's Unicode Tool can do that:Kithttps://downloads.teradata.com/download/tools/unicode-tool-kit

Comment: @dnoeth, I've added full example to my answer

Comment: This still returns *Failure 6706 The string contains an untranslatable character* on 15 & 15.10. On your system there's probably `AcceptReplacementCharacters` in dbscontrol's `internal` field enabled.

Comment: @masospaghetti dit it answer your question? have you find the reason for the error?

Comment: @Dudu Markovitz I marked your response as the answer because it was very helpful and informative. I ended up "solving" this problem by wrapping the query inside another SELECT statement. Teradata cleaned up the data automatically by doing this and got rid of the replacement characters. OREPLACE AND OTRANSLATE don't work in my version of Teradata.

Comment: @masospaghetti, thanks, however this sounds awfully strange... Wrapping your query should have no effect. Could you send me the code please + DDL?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Dudu's excellent answer above, I wanted to add the following now that I've encountered the issue again and had more time to experiment. The following SELECT command produced an untranslatable character:

```
SELECT IDENTIFY FROM PROD_MAE_MNTNC_VW.SCHD_MNTNC;

IDENTIFY
24FEB1747659193DC330A163DCL�ORD
```

Trying to perform a REGEXP_REPLACE or OREPLACE directly on this character produces an error:

```
Failed [6706 : HY000] The string contains an untranslatable character.
```

I changed the CHARSET property in my Teradata connection from UTF8 to ASCII and I could now see the offending character, looks like a tab

```
IDENTIFY
```

[image]

Using the TRANSLATE_CHK command using this specific conversion succeeds and identifies the position of the offending character (Note that this does not work using the UTF8 charset):

```
TRANSLATE_CHK(IDENTIFY USING KANJI1_SBC_TO_UNICODE) AS BADCHAR

BADCHAR
28
```

Now this character can be dealt with using some CASE statements to remove the bad character and retain the remainder of the string:

```
CASE WHEN TRANSLATE_CHK(IDENTIFY USING KANJI1_SBC_TO_UNICODE) = 0 THEN IDENTIFY
ELSE SUBSTR(IDENTIFY, 1, TRANSLATE_CHK(IDENTIFY USING KANJI1_SBC_TO_UNICODE)-1)
END AS IDENTIFY
```

Hopes this helps someone out.

Comment: Thank you so much for TRANSLATE_CHK command. It helped me identify the one offending record amongst 3 million records.