# Untranslatable character when extracting dates from strings

Tags: regex, teradata

I am attempting to extract dates from a free-text field (because our process is awesome like that :\ ) and keep hitting Teradata error 6706. The regex I'm using is: `REGEXP_SUBSTR(original_field,'(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4})',1) AS new_field`. I'm unsure of the field's type `HELP TABLE` has a blank in the Type column for the field.

I've already tried converting using `TRANSLATE(col USING LATIN_TO_UNICODE)`, as well as `UNICODE_TO_LATIN`, those both actually cause the error by themselves. A straight `CAST(original_field AS VARCHAR(255))` doesn't fix the issue, though that cast does work. I've also tried stripping various special characters (new-line, carriage return, etc.) from the field before letting the `REGEXP_SUBSTR` take a crack at it, both by itself and with the CAST & TRANSLATEs I already mentioned.

At this point I'm not sure what the issue could be, and could use some guidance on additional options to try.

Comment: Did you try using regexp_replace to strip out all non-alphanumeric characters?  There's no telling what kind of garbage you might end up with in a really free text field.

Comment: I did a series of `OREPLACE`s. `REGEXP_REPLACE` encountered the same error when I used `'[\r\t\n\e\f]'`, thus why I went with the OREPLACE and the hex codes.

Comment: Have you tried to use the REGEXP_INSTR to find records which contain values outside of the translatable range? Are you running against a view?

Comment: I would try something like rexp_replace, searching for all non-alphanumber characters ([^a-z0-9+]) and replace them with an empty string or something like that.  The exact syntax of the command varies from version to version.  I don't **think** that will puke on the untranslatable character, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Andrew, I attempted your suggestion with an expanded character set `[a-zA-Z0-9+\/.,\-\\ ]`, but still hit the untranslatable character error. Rob, I have not used `REGEXP_INSTR`, I actually wouldn't even be sure what characters aren't translatable to fill in the pattern. I am running against a view though

Comment: Give the `translate_chk()` function a shot. Something like `SELECT original_field FROM your_view WHERE translate_chk(original_field USING UNICODE_TO_LATIN) > 0;` That should identify records with untranslatable unicode hanging out in it. You can follow up and `TRANSLATE(original_field USING UNICODE_TO_LATIN) WITH ERROR` which will translate to latin and drop a `0x1A` when it can't translate.

Comment: So the issue was that I needed to be using `LATIN_TO_UNICODE` rather than `UNICODE_TO_LATIN` to get the `TRANSLATE` to work

Answer (score 0):

The final version that worked ended up being

```
, CASE
    WHEN TRANSLATE_CHK(field USING LATIN_TO_UNICODE) = 0 THEN
        REGEXP_SUBSTR(TRANSLATE(field USING LATIN_TO_UNICODE),'(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4})',1)
    ELSE NULL
END AS Ref_Date
```

For whatever reason, using a `TRIM` inside the `TRANSLATE` seems to cause an issue. Only once I striped any and all functions from inside the `TRANSLATE` did the `TRANSLATE`, and thus the `REGEXP_SUBSTR`, work.

Comment: You might try to check what is actually contained in the bad data using `CHAR2HEXINT(field)`, it's probably hex `1A`, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/40138725

Comment: I had found it via an alternate method. It was ASCII char #26 (backspace).

Comment: Well, hex `1A` equal decimal `26` :-)

Comment: That's weird as I tried using the hex (or at least what I thought is the hex) expression for 1A and still hit the error. Guess I'll have to chalk that up to Hex is ugly & ASCII Char #s are pretty :P